# Scroll down the posts Instagram home page selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, scroll, instagram

I trying scroll down and like posts on the Instagram home page when where I am trying to go next post it's going up again. I am trying to go using the class name of the next post

Here's my code

```
    # Wait 3 second while the post-login page loads
    time.sleep(3)
    bot.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]")\
        .click()
    time.sleep(3)
    bot.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]")\
        .click()
    time.sleep(3)
     #Like the post
    followButton = bot.find_element_by_class_name('fr66n')
    followButton.click()
    time.sleep(5)

    #Go to the comment field
    nex = bot.find_element_by_class_name('sH9wk')
    time.sleep(1)
    nex.click()
    time.sleep(2)
     #Go to next post ...but here it's again going to the first post
    nex_post = bot.find_element_by_class_name('_9AhH0')
    time.sleep(1)
    nex_post.click()
```

Comment: I think you're not scrolling so element isn't appearing in DOM as instagram's pages are dynamic. You have to scroll with ```execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, vertical_pos);")``` and then find posts by class name

Answer (score 0):

To scroll down the page just type this line of code

```
bot.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,700)')
```

instead of 700, you can type the size of the scrolling down